# read value from QVariantist into qml

Tags: qt, qml

I am a complete beginner in Qt and have the following problem. I want to access a certain value from my QVariantList in qml. Here is what I tried:

```
 width: typeof(_styleconfiguration.styleMapping["width"])
```

Unfortunately this call returns me a string. How can I cast it to an Int?

The content of my QVariantList looks like this:

> QMap(("activeBackgroundColor", QVariant(QString,
> "#FFFFFF"))("activeForegroundColor", QVariant(QString,
> "#006381"))("border", QVariant(qlonglong, 1))("borderColor",
> QVariant(QString, "#006381"))("height", QVariant(qlonglong,
> 80))("pressedBackgroundColor", QVariant(QString,
> "#E5F4F9"))("pressedForegroundColor", QVariant(QString,
> "#35322f"))("radius", QVariant(qlonglong, 10))("shadowColor",
> QVariant(QString, "#000000"))("shadowHOffset", QVariant(qlonglong,
> 20))("shadowVOffset", QVariant(qlonglong, 0))("width",
> QVariant(qlonglong, 80)))

Would be happy if someone can help me further.

Comment: Why are you assigning the result from `typeof` to `width`? Are you getting an error using your QVariantList? No casting should be needed.

Comment: @JarMan: thank you for your tip. You are absolutely right. I was not aware that I can leave out the cast. Thanks again